# PayPal in new window call js function on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have to implement a PayPal payment option and I am in a bit of trouble with handling it. I need to open the PayPal login and authorization in a new window or popup ( cause I can't redirect to a new page because of global variables set in js ). The problem is after authorization, I need the window to close and call a function from js so that I can do an Ajax and change some things.

I've tried with onbeforeunload/onunload and it doesn't work :

```
popup.onbeforeunload = function(){
  verifyPayment();
}

popup.location = resp.data.redirect_uri;
window.popup.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
  console.log('ceva');
});
```

These didn't work at all ( something about cross origin resources cause I run it locally with nginx ).
I am using Prestashop and php for PayPal, i just use jQuery to open the window and for ajax calls. Also i don't use the PayPal button, it's something custom. 
Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Read the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-the-checkout-flow/). There is an `onAuthorize` callback that you can use.

Comment: The calls are made from php, i don't have the paypal button for paypal.

Comment: *«The calls are made from php»*... And you understand the difference between server-side and client-side right? PayPal has to be called from client side. And you can't have control over their `iframe` for an obvious security aspect. So if you want a feedback from the authorization, you just can use their callback to JS... And then, do whatever you need to do using Ajax to go back to server-side.

Comment: I am using server side to send the data to PayPal which then returns a response which contains the URL for authorization. I am using js to open that URL in a new window so that a client can login and authorize.

Comment: So I assume you use the API then. I this case, there is "redirect URLs" to be used. Again, you just can't have control over the PayPal window. [Look here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/).

Comment: I know, but the redirect url just open the URL in the window i have opened. I want to close the window and call a function in js when that happens.

Comment: Then put the js you wish to run in that redirect URL... It will run.

Comment: How do i do that? Also i've tried calling a PHP function, which worked but from there i don't have access to the main page JS, just the JS from my new window.

Comment: That's for sure! You have to put the JS you wish to run in the new window. If there is some values to pass on from the old window to the new one, use session variables.